# How to group data in multiple rows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to group data from multiple rows into one row. The issue that I'm having is that I have inherited this data, thousands of rows, and Column A only contains a value when a new data row is started. For example, I have:

[image: Data]

And I need to return:

[image: Results]

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```visual-basic
Sub Merge()
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = [a1].CurrentRegion
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If Len(arr(i, 1)) = 0 Then arr(i, 1) = arr(i - 1, 1)
    If Not d.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        d(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
    Else
        d(arr(i, 1)) = d(arr(i, 1)) & "," & arr(i, 2)
    End If
Next
[d2].Resize(d.Count, 2) = Application.Transpose(Array(d.keys, d.items))
End Sub
```

[image]